# How to sort divs according to their id using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have a set of divs with random ids:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="2"></div>
   <div id="9"></div>
   <div id="7"></div>
   <div id="1"></div>
   <div id="4"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a fast way to sort them according to their id values using jQuery?
Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd use the tinysort plugin:

http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

In your case it would be something like:

`$("#container > div").tsort("",{attr:"id"});`

Comment: This. I had to swallow my pride and admit I couldn't figure out how to get `sort()` working no matter what function I passed to it. I integrate TinySort and my life has never been easier.

Comment: For those finding this by Google, I believe the above example may be outdated. What worked for me with this plugin: `tinysort('#container > div',{attr: 'id'})`

Answer (score 8):

There are plugins and the like to do sorting of elements. If you plan on actually re-ordering the DOM elements, you should probably use one of them.

If you just want a sorted list of the divs, you can use Javascript - since arrays can be sorted using a custom comparison function. You can convert the selected set of `<div>`s into an array using `toArray()` and then sort them using this mechanism.

```
$('#container > div').toArray().sort( function(a,b) { a.id - b.id } );
```

You could also use the `detach()` and `appendTo()` method to remove and the re-insert the elements in sorted order. However, this may not be the most efficient way to re-order the DOM elements.

Comment: This is the correct answer, rater than relying on plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Try my jquery plugin `$.toArrayouter`, using Underscore library.

```
$('#container').html(_.sortBy($('#container>div').toArrayouter(),function (name) {return name} ).join(''))
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/fDZjR/1/