# Sorting DIVs inside other DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort divs according to their id using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351635/how-to-sort-divs-according-to-their-id-using-jquery)

Well I'm having a really hard time trying to solve this and I actually had no sucess until now, I'm trying to sort DIVs inside Other DIVs by ID.
So here's how my DIVs are distribuited in my page

```
<div id="products" >
   <div class="line">
      <div id="Album2">[there are images and even other divs here in each Album]</div>
      <div id="Album1"></div>
      <div id="Album10"></div>
      <div id="Album16"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="line">
      <div id="Album9"></div>
      <div id="Album3"></div>
      <div id="Album4"></div>
      <div id="Album7"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="line">
      <div id="Album5"></div>
      <div id="Album11"></div>
      <div id="Album6"></div>
      <div id="Album13"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="line">
      <div id="Album8"></div>
      <div id="Album14"></div>
      <div id="Album12"></div>
      <div id="Album15"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and this should be my output:

```
  <div id="products" >
       <div class="line">
          <div id="Album1"></div>
          <div id="Album2"></div>
          <div id="Album3"></div>
          <div id="Album4"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="line">
          <div id="Album5"></div>
          <div id="Album6"></div>
          <div id="Album7"></div>
          <div id="Album8"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="line">
          <div id="Album9"></div>
          <div id="Album10"></div>
          <div id="Album11"></div>
          <div id="Album12"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="line">
          <div id="Album13"></div>
          <div id="Album14"></div>
          <div id="Album15"></div>
          <div id="Album16"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

But I have one more problem, all my products are listed and there are more than one page, I was actually able to track them and made a sorted Array of Strings but I didn't had the same luck doing it with the DIVs.
This is my page:
http://biscoitofino.jumpseller.com/catalogo

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set a value attribute to a div and give them numbers. It will be easier to sort then..

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do it, at least within the context of a single page:

```
var lines = $("#products .line");
var elems = $("#products .line div");
for (var index = 1; index <= elems.length; index++) {
    var elemId = "Album" + index;
    var containerIndex = parseInt((index - 1) / 4);
    var container = lines[containerIndex];
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    container.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/dpHyn/

Although I think the *real* answer is, since presumably you've got a server that's providing the list of albums dynamically already, why not just have the server sort the elements properly when it loads them from the database (or whatever other datasource you are using)?  That would save you all this trouble, and work properly with pagination as well.

​

Comment: that's exactly what it is, the Products are been loaded dynamically but the server doesn't contain a sorting by Attribute (Album is an attribute in this case), although the server contains a sorting option for Names and Prices. I'm using Liquid for desigenrs: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers   but I can't implement anything new because I'm using in a pre-made system.

Answer (score 3):

```
var lines = $("#products > .line"),
    albums = lines.children().toArray(),
    line = -1;

albums.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id.replace("Album", "") - b.id.replace("Album", "");
});

$.each(albums, function(i, el) {
    if (!(i % lines.length))
        line += 1;

    lines.eq(line).append(el);
});
```

or without jquery

```
var lines = document.querySelectorAll("#products > .line"),
    line = -1;

[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#products > .line > div"))
    .sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.id.replace("Album", "") - b.id.replace("Album", "");
    })
    .forEach(function(el, i) {
        if (!(i % lines.length))
            line += 1;

        lines[line].appendChild(el);
    });
```

Comment: I like it. Simpler than mine. No reason to post it.

Comment: Thank you so much, but it would work for each page separately, right? It wouldn't work for all the products in all pages, right? Actually, is there any way to sort all the products of all pages, for example, if there's one product with Album name "Aaaa" in page 7, it should come to page 1.