# How to start .each from div id small to biggest number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how i can make the ".each" to starts with the div id small number "1" to the big number "5" ... 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5

lets say i have this divs

```
<div class="TID_5">TID 5</div>
<div class="TID_4">TID 4</div>
<div class="TID_3">TID 3</div>
<div class="TID_2">TID 2</div>
<div class="TID_1">TID 1</div>
```

i have this jquery what im using, but starts with the first div class id number "5" but i need to start with number 1 ...

```
$("div[class*='TID_']").each(function() {
 // code is come here ...
});
```

Comment: if jquery return an array then this will work `$("div[class*='TID_']").reverse() `

Comment: @Ankit: But, jQuery does not return an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery .each() backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards)

Comment: Lets check `ordering` from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351635/how-to-sort-divs-according-to-their-id-using-jquery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
$("div[class*='TID_']").sort(function(e1, e2){
    return $(e1).attr('class') > $(e2).attr('class')
}).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text())
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhvws/2/)

Comment: @F4r-20 it was because the updated version was not set as the base.. fixed now

Comment: thanks works perfect ... but one question how i can find what is the biggest id number ? on my example is = 5

Comment: @MihaiViteazu once teh list is sorted use `.last()` to get the last item the using `.attr('class')` get the class value, from that you can extract the value

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34439/discussion-between-mihai-viteazu-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 3):

You can use index to reverse the elements.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QS4Dq/)**

```
elements = $("div[class*='TID_']")
elements.each(function(index) {
  current = elements.eq(elements.length - index -1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$($("div[class*='TID_']").get().reverse()).each(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/yBZT6/

Answer (score 0):

If your items are ordered in a descendant way all you need to do is a reverse each. You can do it - [as proposed in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards) - like this:

```
$($("div[class*='TID_']").get().reverse()).each(function() { /* ... */ });
```