# Where is the Error in sorting code

Tags: jquery, html

Hey everybody please help I can't find the error

when I press sort...it sort again and again forever

html:

```
<div class="unsorted">
    <div class="labelimagediv" rel="5"> 
      Div 5 here 
    </div> 
    <div class="labelimagediv" rel="3"> 
       Div 3 Here 
    </div> 
     <div class="labelimagediv" rel="4.5"> 
       Div 4.5 here 
    </div>
    <div class="labelimagediv" rel="4">
      Div 4 Here
     </div> </div>
<button class="btnSort">Sort</button>
```

javascript:

```
$("button.btnSort").click(function () {
    var item1 = $('div.labelimagediv')[0];
    var sortedDivs = $(".unsorted").find(item1).toArray().sort(sorter);
    $.each(sortedDivs, function (index, value) {
        $(".unsorted").append(value);
    });
});

function sorter(a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute('rel') - b.getAttribute('rel');
};
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: try it
http://jsfiddle.net/NBKPk/
when I press the sort botton it still sorting and I want only to sort from 1 to 3 one time only

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351635/how-to-sort-divs-according-to-their-id-using-jquery

Comment: At first glance, it is NOT sorting, just moving 1 element. The error seems to be in between the keyboard and the chair.

Comment: I'm not like you "programmer" I'm trying to make my things by myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are sorting one element by selecting the first element `$('div.labelimagediv')[0];`, try this:

```
$("button.btnSort").click(function () {
    $('div.labelimagediv').sort(function(a, b) {
       return a.getAttribute('rel') > b.getAttribute('rel');
    }).appendTo(".unsorted");
});
```

[JsFiddle fork here](http://jsfiddle.net/sh5xS/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var item1 = $('div.labelimagediv')[0];
```

^^ that's just one single element ?

It should be :

```
$("button.btnSort").click(function () {
    var sortedDivs = $('.labelimagediv', '.unsorted').get();
    sortedDivs.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.getAttribute('rel') - b.getAttribute('rel');
    });
    $.each(sortedDivs, function (index, value) {
        $(".unsorted").append(value);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/625QR/1/)