# Reorder DIV's based on element attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item" order="5"></div>
  <div class="item" order="3"></div>
  <div class="item" order="4"></div>
  <div class="item" order="1"></div>
  <div class="item" order="2"></div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, how could I order these divs based on the attribute "order"? By reorder, I mean I would like the dom to update the order of the divs based on the attribute "order". This would naturally adjust the z-index of the divs as well. I know that setting the z-index based on the attribute order will give me the correct display in the browser window, but it won't manipulate the dom order.

I assume I would loop through #container and get the child and its order like so:

```
$('#container > div').each( function(event) {
   var itemOrder = $(this).attr('order');
});
```

...but I'm at a loss on how to manipulate the order. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does this have to do with z-index ?

Comment: Your unclear question has many different answers, please be more specific.

Comment: `z-index` has nothing to do with DOM order.  I'll edit the title to something relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('#container').append($('#container .item').sort(function(a,b){
   return a.getAttribute('order')-b.getAttribute('order');
}));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uKunuTi/1/)

Comment: Nice.  I love the sorting capabilities, with a sorter function, but never thought of doing it directly on the DOM before.  I like that :)

Comment: +1 because it's the first time i know this sort() function exists :)

Comment: Real nice, this one! :-)  +1 for using sort() in an cool, but unexpected way.

Comment: following @undefined's comment: `$('#container > div').sort(function(a,b){
   return parseInt(a.getAttribute('order'))-parseInt(b.getAttribute('order'))
}).appendTo('#container');`

Comment: @A.Wolff What's better there ?

Comment: @undefined - how do you mean, that it would be more readable with appendTo ? As I see it, it's just another way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: Tested and worked like a charm! Thanks @dystroy and everyone else.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Isn't this more _readable_ and just more readable?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775071/where-is-the-error-in-sorting-code/18775148#18775148, however, it's just something subjective.

Comment: @undefined - I say it would depend of the context. And it's as you're saying... It is really a subjective issue.

Comment: @antoine-subit I reverted your buggy edit. There's no `getAttribute` function in jQuery. There's `attr` but when you already have the element, there's no need to wrap it in a jQuery collection because you can directly use  `getAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container > div').each( function(event) {
    $(this).css('z-index', $(this).attr('order'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually want the dom to show the updated order as well

Comment: Perhaps you should re-edit your original question to make it more clear. :)

Comment: @Andrew clearly your question was confusing! Why talking about z-index then?

Answer (score 0):

I think u want this[:DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UuGGW/1/)

```
 $('#container > div').sortElements(function(a, b){
    return parseInt($(a).attr('order')) > parseInt($(b).attr('order')) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: You need to import a plugin to do that !

Comment: its not plugin its a general method used...u can use it to sort elements whether integer ,if string in alphaphtical order.U solution is good and short one i too like it

Comment: `sortElement` isn't a general jQuery function, you have to add it, which makes the code much heavier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to sort divs by attribute "tag" as a single word. JSFiddle has code to check for multiple words, etc. Posting because couldn't find solution when I was looking for it.

```
<div id="tag_sections">
   <!-- populated with sorted divs -->    
</div>
<div id="all_tags">
    <div data-tag="blue">8</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div data-tag="tag">2</div>
    <div data-tag="red">3</div>
    <div data-tag="blue">4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div data-tag="red">6</div>
    <div data-tag="blue">7</div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // sort all by title tag
    var allTags = [];
    $('#all_tags div').each(function() {
       theTag = $(this).attr('data-tag');
       if (!theTag) { theTag = 'ungrouped'; }
       if (!$('#'+theTag).length) {
            allTags.push(theTag);
            $('#tag_sections').append('<div id="'+theTag+'"><h3>'+theTag+'</h3></div>');   
       }
       if ($.inArray(theTag, allTags) > -1) {
           $('#tag_sections #'+theTag).append($(this));
       }
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zyEwF/269/

Demo of sorting by attribute value that is not a number and creates new div to add those sorted elements into.

Answer (score -1):

Try to look here. Could be useful for understanding fundamental principles. http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Comment: this should be a comment