# Sort <a> elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting

How can I sort `<a>` elements with jQuery?

Is it possible? I think there is a right way, but I need advice on how to do it.

```
 <div class="ListOfItems">
    <div class="caption">
<img src="/test1.jpg"/>
    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Name 1
    </a>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="caption">
<img src="/test3.jpg"/>
    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Name 3
    </a>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="caption">
<img src="/test4.jpg"/>
    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Name 4
    </a>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="caption">
<img src="/test2.jpg"/>
    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Name 2
    </a>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I need something like the following :

```
 <div class="ListOfItems">
    <div class="caption">
<img src="/test1.jpg"/>
    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Name 1
    </a>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="caption">
<img src="/test2.jpg"/>
    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Name 2
    </a>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="caption">
<img src="/test3.jpg"/>
    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Name 3
    </a>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="caption">
<img src="/test4.jpg"/>
    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Name 4
    </a>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var els = $('.ListOfItems > .caption').get().sort(function (ob1, ob2) {
    return $.trim($(ob1).find('a').text()).localeCompare($.trim($(ob2)
        .find('a').text()))
})

$.each(els, function () {
    $(this).appendTo('.ListOfItems')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dDmeA/)

Comment: from the title it would seem to be the text of the a elements rather than the value of the src attribute that should be used for sorting

Comment: I need to Sort by <a> elements.

Answer (score 0):

Put your images into div's with corresponding id's (i.e. id="name1", id="name2", etc) and then sort the div's using jQuery TinySort plugin. Here's a similar question and solution:

[How to sort divs according to their id using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351635/how-to-sort-divs-according-to-their-id-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

check  this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CFYnE/36/

Here u can assign data-sid to each div u want to sort and use built in sort function

```
$('.ListOfItems div').sort(function(a,b){
   return a.dataset.sid > b.dataset.sid
}).appendTo('.ListOfItems')
```